# Como obter uma cor de pixel fora do limite de tela no pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pixels

Eu sei que para obter uma cor de um pixel no PyGame eu uso `get_at`.
Mas eu tenho uma imagem de fundo enorme e boa parte dela fica fora da área de tela delimitada pelo pygame.

Por exemplo, uma imagem de 1000x1000 dentro de uma tela de 500x500 terá apenas 50% visível, o restante ficará "fora" da tela. Então eu preciso acessar esta parte FORA da tela do pygame.

Mas se eu fizer referência a `get_at` com uma coordenada maior ou menor que as dimensões da tela, o Pygame dá um erro:

> IndexError: pixel index out of range

```
import pygame
W = 600
H = 400
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([W, H])
image = pygame.image.load('huge_background.png').convert_alpha()
screen.blit(image, [-5000, -420])
pygame.display.update()
screen.get_at([100, -5]) # gera o erro "IndexError: pixel index out of range"
```

Alguém saberia dizer como eu posso acessar um pixel além da área visível da tela pygame?

---

Trata-se de uma simulação de veículos dentro de uma pista.

Aqui está a tela pygame atualmente visível (1600 x 600). As 3 linhas (em magenta) são os "detectores" de colisão:

[image]

E aqui está o plano de fundo (pista) que irá rolar de acordo com a posição do carro (8000 x 8000):

[image]

Esta seria uma visão da tela (quado em vermelho) e do plano global com a imagem de fundo (pista):
[image]

Assim, as linhas do detector de colisão podem exceder os limites da tela do pygame, mas precisam "ler" os pixels externos para detectar a colisão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu `screen` é a tela,  e ele só tem 500x500 pixels - não sabe, e não existe nada fora dele.

No entanto, para desenhar a imagem de fundo, você carrega ela na linha:

```
image = pygame.image.load('huge_background.png').convert_alpha()
```

O objeto guardado na variável `image` nesse caso, assim como sua tela, na variável `screen`, é um `Surface` do pygame. O método `.get_at` é um método da classe Surface.

Então tudo o que você precisa é manter sua imagem lida do disco na variável `image` disponível, e consultar o valor do pixel nela, em vez de na surface - num projeto completo, em vez de nessa demonstração, os valores de deslocamento da imagem de fundo vão estar também em variáveis, em vez dos valores fixos aí `[-5000, -420]`  -

Vamos dizer que você guarde esse valor numa tupla, ou melhor ainda, num Vector2:

```
 offset = pygame.math.Vector2(-5000, -420)
```

Na hora de pedir o valor do pixel "fora da tela", é só adicionar nas coordenadas da tela, o valor negativo desse deslocamento - isso é, o pixel  (0,0) da tela corresponde ao pixel "5000, 420" de `image` - Então é só fazer:

```
offset = pygame.math.Vector2(-5000, -420)
...
# No corpo do código do jogo, mantenha o "offset" atualizado
# se mudar a posição do fundo
...
color = image.get_at([100, -5] - offset) 
# (em vez de screen.get_at([100, -5]) )
```

A classe Vector2 é relativamente nova no Pygame, está disponível a partir 
 do 1.9, se não me engano  - perceba que a grande vantagem dela é que se for somad ou subtraída a com uma tupla, ou outra sequência de duas coordenadas, ele já faz a conta certa para cada componente da coordenada.

Se offset fosse uma tupla normal, em vez de um Vector2, o código teria que ser:

```
color = image.get_at([100 - offset[0], -5 - offset[1])
```

## Importante

Outra coisa digna de nota - os métodos `.get_at`  e `.set_at` de Surfaces do pygame são bons para verificações pontuais - por exemplo, ver se um pixel está dentro de uma área extensa de uma cor, ou mudar um detalhe bem pequeno numa imagem. No entanto, tanto para verificações maiores (se você estiver procurando cores específicas numa área da imagem, por exemplo), eles são bastante lentos - por que envolvem uma chamada de função e criação dinâmica de vários objetos em Python para cada chamada . Isso é:
uma chamada ao `get_at` returna uma tupla de 4 componentes inteiros - internamente, o computador vai pegar os números na memória que representa a imagem, pegar a referência para 4 objetos `int` do Python e criar uma tupla contendo os mesmos. Isso pode ficar de 1000 a 10000 vezes mais lento do que só consultar os valores em sequência na memória.

Então caso esteja manipulando a imagem, o ideal é transformar temporariametne a área manipulada num [surfarray](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html) - isso devolve uma array do [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), que pode acessar os números "inplace" na memória, de forma tremendamente mais eficiente.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela excelente explicação! Aos poucos vou me familiarizando com os conceitos do pygame. Entendi que o conceito de surface, onde a imagem de fundo é um surface e a tela também e podem ser manipulados independentemente.

Comment: Editei a pergunta original e acrescentei algumas imagens e explicações. Entendo que posso usar o `get_at` independentemente na imagem de fundo e não na tela. Mas, além da imagem de fundo, poderão haver OUTROS CARROS e outros objetos 'blitados' anteriormente. Ou seja, seria uma composição da imagem de fundo com outros objetos por cima. Como tratar a colisão neste caso 'composto'?

Comment: a colisão com outros carros tem que ser comparada com relação às coordenadas dos outros carros no jogo, e não com relação a seus pixels na tela - para isso, vamos usar o conceito de Sprites e grupos, e as funções de colisão embutidas no pygame.

Eu sugiro que você desdobre a questão, e faça da dúvida no comentário acima uma outra questão aqui no stackoverflow - já que serão conceitos distintos. Eu ou outra pessoa vamos responder.